# My Firewall Is Blocking YouTube-API Traffic. Which Exceptions Should I Configure?

Tags: youtube, firewall, youtube-api, fiddler

Problem:

- I have code on my developer machine that can successfully publish a video to YouTube via the YouTube API.
- When I move this code to a QA machine, the firewall blocks the YouTube API communication.

Other Information:
 - I've been using Fiddler2, and it seems that the YouTube API needs to communicate with both `YouTube.com` and `uploads.gdata.youtube.com`.

My Question:

> Which firewall exceptions should I
>   configure to permit my web server to
>   communicate with YouTube via the
>   YouTube API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the network traffic.